# Automic: Retrieve files having a specific date of change

Tags: automic, uc4

I am new to Automic deveopment. I want to put Files having a specific date of change, for instance which are older than 60 days to be transferred to a specific folder. Does there exist a function in Automic, and if not, what are other possibilities?

I could not find any function which does the desired job. Only functions accessing the filename, or the content of the file.

Comment: Still relevant? I use a Linux JOBS to get a list of the files using ls or find or whatever. Then I write this output to a VARA object and use this to run a FOREACH workflow. Each step starts a JOBF with only one single name from the list.